# Excel - Function dependency causing no calculation

Tags: vba, excel

I have an issue where formulas aren't updating (I purposely have manual calculation on).  In particular, they are formulas with some complicated dependencies.

```
Cell1:  "=Cell2"
Cell2:  "IFERROR(FindData(X1, X2))"
```

`FindData` is a VBA function I wrote, that uses `Index(Match(X1),Match(X2))` on a predefined range (RangeXYZ).

That range, has a number of formulas that connect to an external data service (not an excel data connection, just another custom vba formula).

When I calculate Cell1, Excel does not calculate any of the downstream things.  I need a way to have it forcecalculate the RangeXYZ, and then recalculate Cell2, then Cell1.

Thanks

EDIT:  I already have, in the sheet Cell1 is contained on:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Application.calculatefull
End Sub
```

but I find this ends in an endless loop of calculates.  I've also tried specifying sheets Sheets("Sheet1").Calculate, but that doesn't seem to work.

A Ctrl-Alt-F9, which does work, is kind of overkill and takes too much time.

Comment: Thanks for the edits R3uK!

Comment: Maybe try to put `Application.Volatile = True` as the first line of `FindData`?

Comment: @VincentG : You beat me to it! ;)

Comment: @keynesiancross : Did you allow recursive calculations in Excel Options? i know it's long but if your file is filled with complicated formulas it's understandable! ;)

Comment: Thats throwing a syntax error - is it Application.Volatile(True)?  I'm just adding it now.   Re; Recursive - don't know? Dont think so?  How do you do that?

Comment: Just `Application.Volatile`, no true needed.

Comment: Yes there should be no =, my mistake

Comment: Trying that, but doesn't seem to work.   I dont think its recalculating the sheet with the external data link

Comment: @R3uK you lost time in editing the post ;)

Comment: But please note that Application.Volatile will make it recalculate every time the sheet is recalculated, not just when the input range changes. This might work in your case, as you have the calculation on manual, but `Application.Volatile` is not a magic cure-all by far, and should only be used with caution.

Comment: @keynesiancross : `Enable iterative calculation` my bad, see https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Remove-or-allow-a-circular-reference-8540bd0f-6e97-4483-bcf7-1b49cd50d123

Comment: Application.Volatile is working.  I think its recalc'ing my entire workbook though (not just the needed ranges).  Anyway to specify the ranges (even if we hijack the Worksheet_Calculate() event handler?).   The workbook has about 3 sheets of external data pulls etc, so the full recalc takes a lot more time then if I specify the needed range.  One of those ranges is realtime data.  The other is static. I only need the realtime to update.

Comment: I also enabled iterative. I think its the Application.Volatile that set it on the right track though.

Comment: You can also try to add a reference to RangeXYZ in the FindData call.

Comment: Ideally you should pass the lookup range to the UDF as an argument. Then it won't need to be volatile.

Comment: what do you mean Vincent?

Comment: If I added the ranges as optional inputs with defaults, would that do the trick?  Ideally I dont need to pass the range (as thats handled within the function already)

Comment: No - you can't do that. It wouldn't work if you could, I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest passing the RangeXYX as a third parameter.  Excel calculation engine probes a workbook testing dependencies and you need to help it out and not fool it with faux optimisations.

If you really want to browbeat Excel calculation engine into doing your bidding then you could try this in your event handler

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Me.Range("RangeXYZ").Calculate
End Sub
```